Can local learning rules minimize a global loss?
It is widely believed that synaptic plasticity is the way biological brains learn. Artificial implementations of this mechanism are for instance local weight-update rules in Spiking Neural Networks. Locality here means that a weight update only depends on things that the post-synaptic neuron 'can see' at the time of the update.
This is in strong contrast to updating all the weights simultaneously by stepping along a gradient of some global loss function.
Question: Have you seen cases where local update rules are proven to minimize a global loss function? Given a loss function, can we formulate update-rules that minimize this loss?
I do not see any reason why local update rules would result in stepping the weights along some gradient field, in general. But maybe in some special cases?
Edit: Hopfield networks seem to do this! The local Hebbian rule does minimze the (global) energy function.

I once tried to optimize a neural network by gradient descending 1 input-output pair at a time ("local in time"), but it did not seem to work for reducing the total global errors even over very many iterations. My theory was that if the optimizer can only see / check 1 output-vs-target result at a time and have to make a decision to adjust a parameter based on just this 1 item error it can see, then in most likelihood this adjustment will in hindsight be a bad decision for the global error overall.
